# Unexpected behaviour in timing function

Tags: javascript, node.js, timing

I try to calculate the time between 2 dates and run some code if the counter is 0 which basically works fine. The issue is when it should run the code, it does not.
For example:

This is the interval

```
setInterval(function() {
    eventCountDown();
}, 1 * 60 * 1000);
```

Then I get some text from the database.

```
function eventCountDown() {
    database.getNextEventDate(function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            calcEventDate(result[0]['event_start'], result[0]['event_end'], result[0]['id']);
        }
    });
}
```

Here I calculate the dates and update the database

```
function calcEventDate(dt, edt, id) {
if (new Date(dt) - new Date() >= 0 && new Date(dt) - new Date() < new Date(edt) - new Date()) {
    dt = new Date(dt);
    var n = new Date();
    var dst = dt - n;

    var d = Math.floor(dst / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var h = Math.floor((dst % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var m = Math.floor((dst % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var s = Math.floor((dst % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if (d == 1 && h == 0 && m == 0) {
        sendMessageToEventChat("initial_message", id);
    } else if (d == 0 && h == 0 && m == 0) {
        //This part is not working fine
        database.updateEventStatus(id, "RUNNING", function(err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                sendMessageToEventChat("start", id);
                initEvent(id);
            }
        });

    }
} 
}
```

As already mentioned... It works. But sometimes it does not update the database end not sending the message. There are no errors and no warnings. I feel like there must be a mistake with `d == 0 && h == 0 && m == 0`

I just noticed that probably none of those functions have been called. Apart from this interval, I have 3 more. One is checking every second but is not accessing the database since interval 2 is doing it every 2 minutes and updates a global variable. Interval 3 is running every 15 minutes. So this shouldn't be the problem.

Could it be that the execution time with the functions interacting with the database is too long? But nodejs should still run the other functions, right?

Any help is appreciated.

### Edit, added logs

```
console.log(new Date(dt) - new Date() >= 0 && new Date(dt) - new Date() < new Date(edt) - new Date());
console.log(d + "D " + h + "H " + m + "M " + s + "S");
console.log(err); //Error from updating event status
console.log(result); // Result form updating event status

true
0D 0H 0M 19S
null
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 1 }
```

Comment: can you add some console.log() to see if and when the code is executed?

Comment: @LioraHaydont I added the logs. Unfortunately currently it's working. I'm trying to set the date to a few hours from now and check if there are any errors. But any error is logged in the console. So I would know if something would not work.